# Amazon Redshift : drop table if exists

Tags: amazon-redshift

Does Redshift support any statement equivalent to the following?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablename
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See next answer; this is **out of date**.

---

Support for

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablename;
```

was added in PostgreSQL 8.2. Redshift is a very heavily modified fork of 8.1 by ParAccel, and as far as I know they've backported very few changes from newer versions. It's very unlikely that it supports `IF EXISTS`; you probably need to do a catalog query to determine if the table exists by looking up `information_schema`, then deciding whether you'll create it based on the result.

Comment: This feature IS supported, see my answer below

Answer (score 28):

This is supported in the latest version of Redshift:

```
DROP TABLE [ IF EXISTS ] name [, ...] [ CASCADE | RESTRICT ]
```

> IF EXISTS Clause that indicates that if the specified table doesn’t
>   exist, the command should make no changes and return a message that
>   the table doesn't exist, rather than terminating with an error.
>
> This clause is useful when scripting, so the script doesn’t fail if
>   DROP TABLE runs against a nonexistent table.

Taken from [online AWS Redshift docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DROP_TABLE.html).